# .Net Core 3 Custom Authorization Policy - Access to Action Verb

Tags: asp.net-core, authorization

I am trying to port some old code over to .Net Core 3.

With the old AuthorizeAttibutes you could get an Action's verb from HttpActionContext
through

`var verb = actionContext.Request.Method.Method;`

In Core 3.0,  HttpActionContext has now changed to AuthorizationHandlerContext.

I have seen some posts mentioning mentioning to use:

`var filterContext = context.Resource as AuthorizationFilterContext;`

`var httpMethod = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Method;`

but in .Net Core 3 I don't see AuthorizationFilterContext on context.Resource for a normal controller or api controller.

Any ideas / pointers as to how I can get the VERB used in the request for the action?

**EDIT**:  So with the help of @xing-zou I was able to do the following POC to get to a unique route key that I can compare with my routes in the db and the roles assigned to them.

If the user belongs to a role that has been associated to a route, then the user will get access otherwise 403 Forbidden

```
    public class AccessToRouteHandler : AuthorizationHandler<AccessToRouteRequirement>
    {
        private readonly IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor;

        private readonly DbContext dbContext;

        public AccessToRouteHandler(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor, DbContext dbContext)
        {
            this.httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(httpContextAccessor));
            this.dbContext = dbContext;
        }

        protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, AccessToRouteRequirement requirement)
        {
            var filterContext = context.Resource as AuthorizationFilterContext;
            var routeInfo = context.Resource as RouteEndpoint;
            var response = filterContext?.HttpContext.Response;

            if (!context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated || string.IsNullOrEmpty(context.User.Identity.Name))
            {
                response?.OnStarting(async () =>
                {
                    filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = (int)System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
                });

                context.Fail();
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            }

            var verb = this.httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Method;
            var routeKey = string.Empty;

            if (context.Resource is Endpoint endpoint)
            {
                var cad = endpoint.Metadata.OfType<ControllerActionDescriptor>().FirstOrDefault();

                var controllerFullName = cad.ControllerTypeInfo.FullName;
                var actionName = cad.ActionName;
                var bindings = cad.Parameters;
                var actionParams = ".";

                if (bindings.Any())
                {
                    bindings.ToList().ForEach(p => actionParams += p.ParameterType.Name + ".");
                }

                routeKey = $"{controllerFullName}.{actionName}{actionParams}{verb}";
            }

            var route = dbContext.Routes
                .Include(t => t.Roles)
                .FirstOrDefault(r => r.RouteKey == routeKey);

            if (route != null && route.Roles.Any(role => context.User.HasClaim(c => c.Value == role)))
            {
                // user belong to a role associated to the route.
                context.Succeed(requirement);
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            }

            response?.OnStarting(async () =>
            {
                filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = (int)System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Forbidden;
            });

            context.Fail();
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Just to be clear: You are casting it to `AuthorizationFilterContext` and accessing its property on `filterContext` right? `AuthorizationFilterContext` is not a property of `context.Resource`

Comment: If cast to `AuthorizationFilterContext` the result is always null as this type is not present in the metadata collection.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In asp.net core 3.0  with endpoint routing enabled, you could register `IHttpContextAccessor` to get the current HttpContext, then you could get the `http` method.

Take below Policy-based authorization as an example:

```
public class AccountRequirement : IAuthorizationRequirement { }

public class AccountHandler : AuthorizationHandler<AccountRequirement>
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

    public AccountHandler(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(httpContextAccessor));
    }
    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(
        AuthorizationHandlerContext context,
        AccountRequirement requirement)
    {

        var httpMethod = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Method;

        if (httpMethod == "POST")
        {
            context.Succeed(requirement);
        }


        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

In Startup:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        //...
        services.AddControllersWithViews();
        services.AddRazorPages();
        services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
        services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("Account",
                              policy => policy.Requirements.Add(new AccountRequirement()));
        });

        services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, AccountHandler>();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks @xing-zou    This was exactly what I was after to build the complete route namespace.

Comment: @Kiewiet Great! Could you accept the answer if you have resolve the problem?

Comment: Perfect! This was exactly what I needed to access the route values in my auth handler. Thank you!